# noexcept for different operations with template type inside function

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, noexcept

I want to write a template function foo, that do some operations on type T, and inside this function values of type T can be:

- copied
- assigned
- summed with operator+

So, I need to specify noexcept for this function with restrictions I've mentioned above.

Here is my code, but it isn't work properly:

```
template<class T>
void foo() 
    noexcept(noexcept(std::declval<T>() + std::declval<T>()) && std::is_copy_constructible<T>::value && std::is_assignable<T, T>::value)
{}

bool b1 = noexcept(foo<int>()); // false, but should return true
bool b2 = noexcept(foo<std::string>()); // false
```

What should I do, to make it work right?

Comment: _"So, I need to specify noexcept for this function"_ I fail to see the causality. Why not simply use sfinae?

Comment: @YSC in this certain situation I can't use SFINAE

Comment: This will only work if `operator+(T,T)` is defined `noexcept`. What [if it's not](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/786d48b2253bfce0)?

Comment: @YSC this is just my attempt to define this function with such operator+, if you know another way of solving this problem, please write it here

Comment: Well, sfinae but you said you could (aren't allowed?) not.

Comment: @YSC I should solve this task in terms of noexcept, but it will be interesting to see solution with sfinae

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`noexcept(foo<int>());` is false because `std::is_assignable<int, int>::value` is false, e.g. you cannot write `1 = 1`. What you might have wanted to do is to use `std::is_assignable<T&, T>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You try to check the existence of a `T operator+(T,T)` with `noexcept()`, but this will only detect `noexcept operator+`. In my opinion, we can do better.

```
namespace detail
{
    template<class>
    struct sfinae_true : std::true_type{};

    template<class T>
    static auto can_add(int) -> sfinae_true<decltype(std::declval<T>() + std::declval<T>())>;

    template<class>
    static auto can_add(long) -> std::false_type;
}
template<class T>
struct can_add : decltype(detail::can_add<T>(0))
{};
```

This defines a trait to check if, for a given type `T`, the expression `T{}+T{}` bears meaning.

Test cases:

```
struct s1 {};
s1 operator+(s1,s1) { return s1{}; }

struct s2 {};
s2 operator+(s2 const&, s2 const&) { return s2{}; }

struct s3 {};

#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << can_add<s1>::value << "\n"; // true
    std::cout << can_add<s2>::value << "\n"; // true
    std::cout << can_add<s3>::value << "\n"; // false
}
```

---

You can then define:

```
template<class T>
struct is_foo_compatible : std::conjunction<
    can_add<T>,
    std::is_copy_constructible<T>,
    std::is_assignable<T&, T>
> {};
```

And It Just Works™.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `std::is_assignable<int, int>` (which is `false`). You cannot in general assign to an `int`, only to an `int&` (i.e. an l-value reference, which implies the existence of an actual object that you're modifying). Without the reference qualifier, r-values would have to be assignable as well (for example the statement `1=1` would have to be valid).

So change your `T` to a `T&` in the `std::is_assignable` expression.